# CakePHP App with Apache Alias of subdirectory pointed at different CakePHP code directory causing infinite redirect to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have two websites, both of them are CakePHP. They are served at **domaina.com** and **domainb.com**, and have the document roots `/home/weba/root` and `/home/webb/root` respectively. I need to serve the url **domaina.com/directory** from a different directory than the `DocumentRoot`:`/home/webb/root` and not `/home/weba/root` like is configured in the VHost below.

I've tried Alias and AliasMatch, and the furthest I've gotten is getting the URL to throw a "Too Many Redirects" error by adding index.php onto the domain until it looks like: **domaina.com/directory/index.php/index.php/index.php/index.php...**

I think what is causing the infinite redirect is the .htaccess file in `/home/webb/root/app/webroot/`

This is what I have that is causing that:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "/home/weba/root"

ServerName www.domaina.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
SSLCertificateFile ...
SSLCertificateKeyFile ...
SSLCertificateChainFile ...
<Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Files>
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

    AliasMatch "^/directory(.*)" "/home/webb/root"
    <Directory "/home/webb/root">
        Options All -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0


CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Note that each code base has an standard CakePHP .htaccess file directing everything to /app/webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The other .htaccess in app/webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:
I've even tried adding a symbolic link: `/home/weba/root/app/webroot/directory` to link to `/home/webb/root/app/webroot` which kind of works, but anything not that symbolic link directory (say domaina.com/directory/page) ends up getting served from domaina's root directory, since it no longer matches the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` rule, as expected -- which makes me think the Symbolic link route is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't get the exact requirements you want to meet.

I will try first not removing RewriteBase, and naming it as the subolder you are using.

Finally, I think you should try to control both if mod_rewrite is working, and also if some directive in the apache domain file is interfering with your htaccess rules.

But I think you will get more feedback if you simplify your question with the base requirements you need.

Without more information, I can only point you to an htaccess tester:

http://www.htaccesscheck.com/

To verify your syntax and which rules are applying.

EDIT:

After reading your changes, I think I know what you are trying to do, to serve the main application from its web root, but urls under some directory to be handled by other app or web root. I've acomplished it like this ( but written under the Apache .conf file, not within the .htaccess )

```
I've made something similar to host a blog with wordpress, but I put all this directives under the conf file:


<Directory /path/to/my/web/app>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>

Alias /blog /path/to/my/web/blog
<Directory /path/to/my/web/blog>
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
allow from all
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
</Directory>
```

The Options parts are optional, I've leaved for being accurate with my config.

With this I can serve the /blog urls with a wordpress installed in other directory. Don't know if this is what you're trying to get.

Comment: I have edited the question to be clearer with my problem

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you have a base site domain.com pointed to a webroot 'x', and additionally, you want to serve what's behind domain.com/somedir from other different webroot 'y' ?

Edit ( Sorry I pressed enter ): I've made something similar to host a blog with wordpress, but I put all this directives under the conf file: